# How do I make all the docstring using triple double quotes instead of triple single quotes?

Tags: python, pycharm, sublimetext, docstring

I have a long source code in python, and many functions are documented with `'''xxx'''`, How do I replace them with `"""xxx"""` quickly? in any text editor ?  pycharm / sublime

```
def my_func():
    '''
    yeah a doc string
    '''
    pass
```

desired result:

```
def my_func():
    """
    yeah a doc string
    """
    pass
```

edit:
Found the solution in pycharm ( or every other text editor)
search for 
`'''(\n.*\n\s*)'''\n`
and replace with
`"""$1"""\n`

ps: I can not just do a simple search for `'''`,and replace it with `"""`, because in the code multi line strings are everywhere, not just in the docstring.

Comment: Find and Replace...Replace All ?

Comment: Do you *seriously* not know how to do this? Find `'''` and Replace With `"""`?

Comment: Regular expressions are your friend if you have lots of files: `find path/to/dir -name '*.py' -exec perl -p -i -e \'s/'''/"""/g\' {} \;`

Comment: @MattDMo it's hard because I have many `'''` which are for multiline strings in the code, I don't want to break them

Comment: You could try a tool like [`docformatter`](https://github.com/myint/docformatter).  It might change your docstrings in _other_ ways though...

Comment: @mgilson This should be the correct answer, Thanks! I will choose this as answer if you can add one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve it by three methods,

#### Method 1: Inspect whole project

Go to `Code > Inspect Code`. PyCharm will scan your code (this may take some time) and will show you the inspection results.

In the inspection results, under Python It will show `Single Quoted docstrings`
[image]

1. **To change all the files at once** 
   Select `Single quoted docstring` from the left pane and click `Convert docstring to the triple double quoted string form`. Now all the files will be changed to triple double quotes.
2. **To change for individual files** 
   Select individual files under `Single quoted docstring` and for each file click `Convert docstring to the triple double quoted string form`.

#### Method 2: Replace Code with `Replace in Path`

In PyCharm, right click on the project and select **`Replace in Path`** or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
[image]
[image]

In the `Text to find` field, enter `'''` and in `Replace with` field, enter `"""`. click find. PyCharm will scan through the files and ask you whether to replace  single occurrence, or all occurences at once.

#### Method 3: Use terminal tools or Python to read lines and replace.

As others mentioned, this method will do the job.

> **I recommend method 1** Since PyCharm is intelligent, it can change doctrings without changing multi-line strings (if you are using it) which is prone to replacement in other methods.

Answer (score 0):

In vi:

```
:%s/'''/"""/g *<return>*
```

Comment: How much do you want to bet someone complains after they type in `*<return>*`?

Comment: This is useful, but inconvenient if you have lots of files. You have to open, edit, and `:wq` every single one of them. Yuck :(

Answer (score 0):

```
python -c "import sys;with open(sys.argv[1],'rb') as f: tmp = f.read();with open(sys.argv[1],'wb') as f:f.write(tmp.replace(\"'''\",'\"\"\"')"
```

Comment: Mine is shorter 

Answer (score 0):

Turning my comment into an asnwer. Regular expressions are your friend if you have lots of files. From a GNU/Linux terminal, you can write:

```
find path/to/dir -name '*.py' -exec perl -p -i -e \'s/'''/"""/g\' {} \;
```